# Get the name of the next commit with git

Tags: git, version-control, repository, branch

What I want to do is checkout a specific commit based on the commitId, but then I want to check out the commit that came just after the one I'm on. Is there any way to do this without using the commitId of the commit after the one I'm using? Or is there away to find out how far away from the current branch what I have is?

Basically I have the commitId of a revision that is X away from the head. I need to figure out how to get the commitId of the version that is X-1 away from the main or just find out what X is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git name-rev --name-only HEAD
```

This will give you a useful name, such as `master~6`, or `tags/mytag~2`, that you can use to easily name the next commit (i.e. `master~5` or `tags/mytag~1`).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Needed to wait 3 minutes but I went out to lunch haha. Accepted now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checked out at a revision that is X commits behind a given branch (lets call it `master`, you could do this:

```
git log --pretty=oneline HEAD..master | wc -l
```

That should return the number of commits between you and the `master` branch

Hope this helps.